# pre-selecting material radio button using reactive forms not working

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have an Angular Material radio button group containing two radio buttons. I'm using Reactive Forms and want to pre-select the first radio button which has a value of 'true'.

I initialize the value of the associated FormControl as part of a FormGroup like so:

```
userFormGroup = new FormGroup({
  orgType: new FormControl(true),
  ...
})
```

I verified the value is set to true by adding this code beneath the radio group:
`<p>orgTypeBool value: {{userFormGroup.get('orgType').value}}</p>`. The value does return 'true'.

I tried pre-selecting the first radio button by using the selected Input decorator as mentioned in the material radio button documentation: https://material.angular.io/components/radio/api#MatRadioGroup. When I try it out I get the following error: `TypeError: Cannot create property 'checked' on boolean 'true'`.

Here is my code:

```
<mat-radio-group formControlName="orgTypeBool" [selected]="userFormGroup.get('orgType').value" (change)="controlChange()">
    <mat-radio-button id="nonprofit" value="true">Non-Profit</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button id="commerical" value="false">Commerical</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
<p>orgTypeBool value: {{userFormGroup.get('orgType').value}}</p>
```

I think there's a way to do it using `[selected]` but I don't know what the right syntax would be. How would I pre-select the first radio button based on the FormControl's value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Not sure if it's best practice.

I added a checked Input decorator to the first radio button and set it to 'true'.

```
<mat-radio-group formControlName="orgTypeBool" (change)="controlChange()">
    <mat-radio-button id="nonprofit" value="true" [checked]="true">Non-Profit</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button id="commerical" value="false">Commerical</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

Comment: The html **selected** attribute can be added to options to preselect default values. It should work in this case.
You can add it to one of the options like so:
`<mat-radio-button id="nonprofit" value="true" selected>Non-Profit</mat-radio-button>`

Comment: Seeing you are using Reactive forms, you can also set the default radio button choice by pre-filling the FormGroup / ControlName of orgTypeBool, in the Initial Form value setup.

Comment: your actual problem is the form implementation on the UI, please have a look at the example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2vpcka?file=src%2Fapp%2Fradio-ng-model-example.html

Answer (score 0):

In template: `value="true"` - **string** 'true', while in component: `new FormControl(true)` - **boolean** true. They are not equal thus radio button is not pre-selected.